# Which code is running when device is off and USB is plugged in?

Tags: android

Would this be the bootloader or some other code?

I looked for the code in u-boot bootloader but didn't find any code that would be executing at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That strongly depends on the specific device, however, some devices will boot the kernel, but not android, and charge there, others will use recovery mode, and yet others will have third methods.